# Starting Outlook and open existing mail

Tags: objective-c, macos, command-line, outlook, office365

I need open existing mail by id in outlook from my app. Is this possible on osx?

current code:

```
NSString* mailID = ...
...
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[workspace fullPathForApplication:@"Microsoft Outlook.app"]];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", @"", nil];
[workspace launchApplicationAtURL:url options:0 configuration:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arguments forKey:NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments] error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: The Outlook starts, but it is not clear how to automatically open a letter.